# RDFLIB : SPARQL count query gives an inappropriate output

Tags: sparql, rdflib

I am new to python and SPARQL. I am trying to get the count of the metadata where the subject is "social sciences" from a list of .ttl files. I am using the below code. However, the output which I get seems to be an error. Could someone please shed some light?

```
files = Path(r'D:\Masterproject\Metadata_PP\Test_Input').glob('*.ttl')
graph = Graph()
for file in files:
    graph.parse(file, format='ttl')

knows_query ="""
SELECT ?mdata (count(distinct ?mdata) as ?count)
WHERE {
?mdata dcterms:creator ?author .
?mdata dcterms:title ?title .
?mdata dcterms:subject ?area .
?mdata dcterms:subject ?o FILTER ( str(?o) = "Social sciences" ) . 
}
GROUP BY ?mdata
"""

qres = graph.query(knows_query)
#to append the SPARQL results in an output .txt file
for row in qres:
    mdata = (f"{row.mdata}|{row.count}")
    print(mdata)
```

Output I get is :

```
http://doi.org/10.17026/dans-zgj-fdpf|<built-in method count of ResultRow object at 0x000002485D5198B0>
```

In the second column, I expect output as "1"

Comment: not sure about the result itself, but looking as a comment regarding your query, what is the purpose of the `count` in your query? I mean, it will always be `1`

Comment: but yes, looks weird that the aggregate function isn't evaluated to a literal, but maybe you can try to call `get_value` on it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `{row.count}`, use `{row['count']}`. This will avoid using the colliding identifier for the `count` method. (Alternatively, you could rename the `?count` method to some other name that wouldn't collide with the `count` method.)

Comment: ah, right - an interesting Python thing - there is a `count` method on the `ResultRow` object. Nice to know (the error message also indicates this, should have read it more carefully). Cheers